# capture with if-then-else in php regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm very lost with a regular expression. It's just black magic to me. Here's what i need:

- there is a filename: some_file.jpg
- it might be in the following format: some_file_p250.jpg
- the regex to match the file in simple format: /^([a-zA-Z_-0-9]+).(jpg|jpeg|png)$/
- the regex to match the file in advanced format: /^([a-zA-Z_-0-9]+)(_[a-z]?[0-9]{2,3}).(jpg|jpeg|png)$/

my question is as follows: how do i make the "(_[a-z]?[0-9]{3,4})" part optional? I've tried adding a question mark to the second group like this:

```
/^([a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+)(_[a-z]?[0-9]{3,4})?\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/
```

Even though the pattern works, it always captures the contents of the second group in the first group and leaves the second empty.

How can i make this work to capture the filename, advanced part (_p250) and the extension separately? I'm thinking it has something to do with the greediness of the first group, but i might be completely wrong and even if i'm right, i still don't know how to solve it.

Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: What language are you writing this in? Perl?

Comment: @Imortenson It is in PHP's PCRE (perl compatible regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a question mark after the first plus will make the first capturing expression non-greedy.  This worked for me using your test case:

```
/^([a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+?)(_[a-z]?[0-9]{3,4})?\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/
```

I tested in Javascript, not PHP, but here's my test:

```
"some_file_p250.jpg".match(/^([a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+?)(_[a-z]?[0-9]{3,4})?\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)
```

and my results:

```
["some_file_p250.jpg", "some_file", "_p250", "jpg"]
```

In my experience, making a capturing expression non-greedy makes regular expressions a lot more intuitive and will often make them work the way I expect them to work.  In your case, it was doing what you suspected; the first expression was capturing everything and never gave the second expression a chance to capture anything.

Comment: Thanks very much. This worked fine in PHP as well in all test cases. And the worst part is that it turns out i knew how to disable the greediness myself, but still didn't come up with it. Thanks again, i'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
/^([a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+)(|_[a-z]?[0-9]{3,4})?\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/
```

or

```
/^([\d\w\-]+)(|_[a-z]?[0-9]{3,4})\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've just tried both of these with test data "testme_p250.jpg". The entire "testme_p250" was matched with the first group. The second didn't match anything and the third matched the extension. So what do you think went wrong?

Comment: How do you want the output?

Comment: As stated in the question, i want all three groups separately.